# Determine whether a function $f$ satisfying $\int_{B_{2r}\setminus B_r}|f(x)|^3dx<Cr$, for every $r$ is $L^1(B_1)$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $B_r=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<r\}$ denote the ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at the origin or radius $r$. Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying:

There exists a constant $C>0$ such that for every $r>0$:
$$\int_{B_{2r}\setminus B_r}|f(x)|^3dx<Cr\;\;\;\; \text{ and }\;\;\;\;\int_{B_{2r}\setminus B_r}|g(x)|^4dx<Cr^{-7}$$

Determine whether $f\in L^1(B_1)$ and whether $g\in L^1(B_1)$. Further, in addition, if $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be continuous, then show that $fg\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I'm unable to see the relationship between $\int_{B_1}|f|$ and the given property that $f$ satisfies. Likewise for $g$. I'm looking for hints only. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hölder's inequality with the exponents $p=3$ and $q=\frac32$ gives
$$
\int_{B_{2r}\setminus B_r}|f|\cdot1
\leq
\big(\int_{B_{2r}\setminus B_r}|f|^3\big)^{\frac13}
\big(\int_{B_{2r}\setminus B_r}1\big)^{\frac23}
\leq cr^{1/3}\cdot r^{4/3}.
$$
Then the question is about summability of these.

Comment: Thanks, I can take it from here.

Comment: @timur I know this is old, but the same treatment for $g$ doesn't give a convergent series. That doesn't necessarily imply that it is not $L^1(B_1)$. But I'm having difficulty constructing a counterexample. Could you please treat the case for $g$?